# Approach to find partial sum formula

Tags: summation, partial-fractions

The partial sum formula for $$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{k}{(k+1)!}$$ is given by $$1-\dfrac{1}{(n+1)!}$$
I'm interested in the approach to reach there. How do you prove it without induction?

Comment: Maybe you can expand the sum and see if you can cancel out some terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\frac k{(k+1)!}=\frac{(k+1)-1}{(k+1)!}=\frac1{k!}-\frac1{(k+1)!}$. Therefore, your sum is a telescopic sum.

Comment: I wish if I had the same eyes as you own.

Comment: Keep practicing and you will.

Comment: @user571036 Jose's eyes are indeed excellent, but this is an old question. The neatness of the formula for the partial sums also gives us a bit of a hint as well, as you can view it as $a_1 - a_{n+1}$ for the null-convergent sequence $a_n = \frac{1}{n!}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a probabilistic proof.  Let $[n]:=\{0,1,2,\ldots,n\}$.  Consider the set $S$ of all permutations on $[n]$.  Equip $S$ with the uniform discrete probability measure $\mathbb{P}$.  The event $E$ that a randomly picked permutation $\Sigma$ is not the identity clearly has the probability of $$1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\,.$$

Now, we argue this way.  For $k=1,2,\ldots,n$, let $E_k$ denote the event that $$\Sigma(0)<\Sigma(1)<\Sigma(2)<\ldots<\Sigma(k-1)\text{ but }\Sigma(k)<\Sigma(k-1)\,.$$  Then, prove that $E_1,E_2,\ldots,E_n$ are pairwise disjoint events, $\displaystyle\bigcup_{k=1}^n\,E_k=E$, and $$\mathbb{P}\left(E_k\right)=\frac{k}{(k+1)!}\,.$$